# Modifying SelectList items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist

I've been struggling with SelectList and decided to try a simple experiment:

```
SelectList list = new SelectList(db.People.OrderBy(x => x.Last), "ID", "Last", sItem);
foreach (SelectListItem item in list)
{
  item.Text = item.Text.ToUpper();
}
return list;
```

When it gets to the end, inspecting list shows the items are unmodified. What gives? Obviously  missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq projection to create your SelectList items:

```
var toupper = db.People.OrderBy(x => x.Last)
                       .Select(x => new
                           {   
                              Id = x.Id,  
                              Last = x.Last.ToUpper(), //Whatever you want to upper case
                              Whatever = x.Whatever
                              // Add other items you want to show in select list
                           });

SelectList list = new SelectList(toupper, "Id", "Last", sItem);

return list;
```